# How spring-cloud-function-deployer deploy/undeploy function at runtime?

Tags: spring-cloud-function

I am trying to build my own faas service.I want to support load the function at runtime.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class DeployerApplication {

    FunctionCatalog catalog;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0/5 * * * * ?")
    void loadSomething() {
        String[] args = new String[]{
            "--spring.cloud.function.location=./faas-function/target/faas-function-1.0-SNAPSHOT-boot.jar",
            "--spring.cloud.function.function-class=com.example.Tmp"};

        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(TmpApplication.class, args);
        catalog = context.getBean(FunctionCatalog.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DeployerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @SpringBootApplication(proxyBeanMethods = false)
    private static class TmpApplication {

    }
}
```

but when I run those code, I got those

```
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.boot.admin.SpringApplicationAdminMXBeanRegistrar.afterPropertiesSet(SpringApplicationAdminMXBeanRegistrar.java:129) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

How spring-cloud-function-deployer deploy/undeploy function at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad, so . . .
There is an [integration test case in the project](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/blob/master/spring-cloud-function-deployer/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/function/deployer/FunctionDeployerTests.java) git repository as well as [individual projects](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-function/tree/master/spring-cloud-function-deployer/src/it) demonstrating several supported scenarios (i am sure you'll find the one that fits you), Please have a look and feel free to follow up with more concrete questions.